# laravel 4 return HTTP VERB passed to route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

how can I return or print "HTTP VERB" that passed to route?

```
Route::any('/', function()
{
    return "HTTP VERB";
}
```

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you're looking for the [request method](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#request-information):

```
$method = Request::method();
```